# How to make a variable hold its value through a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I have an object that I call with an instance that lives in a loop set up with a timer. When calling the object I give a parameter.Every time the object is called the value of this parameter resets to 0, which is the initial value. What I want is the value to not reset and to hold the value it gets from the last loop.

This is the object:

```
namespace OpenSea_API.Collections
{
    public class Collection
    {
        //more code
        private double initialValueOffer;
        public Collection(double initialValueOffer //more code)
        {
            //more code
            this.initialValueOffer = initialValueOffer;
        }
        public async Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
           //more code
                }
               //more code
                    if (bestOfferInCollection != initialValueOffer) 
                    {
                        if ((//more code)
                        {
                            initialValueOffer = CalculateMyOfferNumber(2.5, 5, initialValueOffer);
                          //more code
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the timer setup and the instance of this object:

```
static async Task Main()
    {
        timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
        timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) => await TimerElapsedAsync();
        timer.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Stop the timer when exiting the program
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    private static async Task TimerElapsedAsync()
    {
        var FlowerLolitaCollections = new Collection(OfferVariables.initialValueOfferFlowerLolitaCollections //more code);
await FlowerLolitaCollections.ExecuteAsync();
    }
```

And this is the class where initialValueOfferFlowerLolitaCollections lives:

```
public static class OfferVariables
    {
        public static double initialValueOfferFlowerLolitaCollections;
    }
```

As you can see in the first loop initialValueOffer = 0 and it gets the value of 5 (for example) when CalculateMyOfferNumber() is executed.
Now, when we get to the second loop and I execute the instance again and give the parameter OfferVariables.initialValueOfferFlowerLolitaCollections, it does not remember the value of 5, but instead is 0.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You don't have to do anything to make a variable retain its value. That's what variables do: they hold a value. It won't spontaneously disappear or change for no reason. If you see a variable value change, it's because you changed it, and you can find out where using the debugger that comes as part of VS. Apart from that, there are no loops in the code you posted. Please update your question so it makes sense.

Comment: This code needs to be redesigned. That's not a variable, that's a field that exists only as long as the object exists. Each time the timer fires a *new* "Collection" object is created. There's no expectation that one object's fields will appear inside another object

Comment: One option, assuming `ExecuteAsync` finishes before the timer fires again, is to store `Collection` as a static field in `Program.cs` and create it only once in `Main`

Comment: BTW: `if (bestOfferInCollection != initialValueOffer)` assuming both are `double`, this might not behave as you would expect. => Floating Point Arithmetics.

Comment: Declare `FlowerLolitaCollections` as a static field of `Program`, instead of a local (temporary) variable of `TimerElapsedAsync`, then instantiate it only once (immediately on declaration or inside `TimerElapsedAsync` only if is still `null`).

Comment: I declared FlowerLolitaCollections as a static field of Program, instead of a local (temporary) variable of TimerElapsedAsync, then instantiated it only once (immediately on declaration or inside TimerElapsedAsync only if is still null). It works. Thank you guys. But I don't see an option how to mark the questions as answerd.

Comment: You can only mark an answer as the "accepted" one. But: if no one else answers, it is totally fine to post your fixed solution as an answer yourself and accept it.